# NiFi ReplaceText Behaving Differently

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a CSV file that I've introduced into my pipeline (for testing purposes) in two ways. First, I'm using `GetFile` to read it in from the server file system. Second, I'm using `GenerateFlowFile`. The content of these files is identical; I copied and pasted the content from the `GetFile` output to insert as text into `GenerateFlowFile`. Yet, when I run these through a `ReplaceText` processor, I am seeing different results.

The file from `GenerateFlowFile` is working as expected, and the regex string in `ReplaceText` is being found and replaced with an empty string exactly as I want. But, the file from `GetFile` is returning a file with no change after running through `ReplaceText`. How is this possible, and how can I fix this?

I tried to create a reproducible example, but I'm only seeing the issue with my data and can't replicate it with non-PII data. If it makes a difference, the regex used in `ReplaceText` is `^.*"\(Line.*,\n` and the replacement value is an empty string set. Essentially, I want to drop the extraneous first line.

Comment: i believe the `Character Set`of the file and generateFlowFile is different.

Comment: Can you examine the file contents in a hex viewer (`xxd`, HexFiend, etc.) to see if there are any non-printable characters on the first line? This could be causing the different behavior. On the other hand, if you want to remove the first line regardless of content, use the regex `^.*?\n`, which should remove the content starting at the content boundary until (and including) the first new line character.

Comment: @Andy I viewed in hex and I didn't see anything non-printable on the first line as far as I could tell. And `^.*?\n` didn't seem to have any effect on the file either :/

Comment: You said you couldn't reproduce with non-PII data; can you copy the problematic file and replace the PII data values with innocuous values so it can be shared here? You can also examine the flowfile content in original/formatted/hex views in NiFi's content viewer directly (before and after the `ReplaceText` operation occurs) to try and detect differences.